# migrating from legacy password to rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm migrating from a legacy system that uses simple MD5 unsalted passwords into Devise.  While I could roll my own encryptor as recommended on the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-custom-encryptor) I actually want to **migrate** to the bcrypt password mechanism.

This also seems more reasonable than downloading rainbow tables and trying to discover all the plaintext passwords...

So, I'm wondering if there might be any side-effects to the following code, especially around the save! triggering any callbacks that have unintended behavior:

```
## config/initializers/legacy.rb
require 'bcrypt'
require 'digest/md5'

module Devise
  module Models
    module DatabaseAuthenticatable
      def valid_password?(password)
        if self.legacy_password_hash
          if ::Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password) == self.legacy_password_hash
            ## authenticated; now convert to bcrypt password
            self.password = password
            self.legacy_password_hash = nil
            self.save!
            return true
          else
            ## so that we don't get a bcrypt invalid hash exception
            return false
          end
        else
          return ::BCrypt::Password.new(self.encrypted_password) == "#{password}#{self.class.pepper}"
        end            
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Trying to discover plain text passwords would probably be unethical anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly stolen from:

http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/9dcf87b2225bd11f?pli=1

In short, do not override `Devise`'s default authentication. Just put this method into your authentication model (usually `User`).